# How to build Insert into with select statement that uses constant values using JOOQ Query Builder

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have an insert statement that is inserting some constant values and it needs to select some reference keys from other tables by lookup. The query looks something like this.

```
Insert into repository.buffer (
    b_external_id,
    b_buffer_type_id,
    b_entrypoints,
    b_site_id,
    b_state,
    b_uri)
select '100A',bt_id,'["/locations/100A"]'::jsonb,s_id,'ready','/buffers/100A'
from  repository.site, repository.buffer_type
where s_name = 'bar'
and bt_external_id = 'FOO';
```

My JOOQ Query Builder code looks like this

```
dslContext
            .insertInto(
                table("repository.buffer"),
                field("b_external_id"),
                field("b_buffer_type_id"),
                field("b_entrypoints"),
                field("b_site_id"),
                field("b_state"),
                field("b_uri"))
            .select(select(
                    inline(null, String.class),
                    field("bt_id"),
                    inline(null, Object.class),
                    field("s_id"),
                    inline(null, String.class),
                    inline(null, String.class))
                    .from(table("repository.site"), table("repository.buffer_type"))
                    .where(field("s_name").eq(cast(null, String.class)))
                    .and(field("bt_external_id").eq(cast(null, Integer.class))))
                .onConflict().doNothing()
            .getSQL();
```

This statement fails to compile with following error

```
Error:(98, 25) java: incompatible types: org.jooq.SelectConditionStep<org.jooq.Record6<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record6<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>>
```

Somehow as soon as I use inline in the select return type of select changes to SelectConditionStep instead of Select.

Any clue to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the compiler infers `SelectConditionStep` is irrelevant here, as it is a subtype of `Select`, and as such, totally acceptable for the `INSERT .. SELECT` statement. The problem is that when using plain SQL in your `insertInto()` clause and not providing any column data types, the compiler will infer `Object` for each individual column, instead of `String`.

Remember that jOOQ is a very strongly typed API and this mostly helps you get your SQL right. In your particular case, make sure you will specify a data type on each column reference:

```java
dslContext
    .insertInto(
        table("repository.buffer"),
        field("b_external_id", String.class), // Change here
        field("b_buffer_type_id"),
        field("b_entrypoints", Object.class), // Change here
        field("b_site_id"),
        field("b_state", String.class), // Change here
        field("b_uri", String.class)) // Change here
    .select(select(
            inline(null, String.class),
            field("bt_id"),
            inline(null, Object.class),
            field("s_id"),
            inline(null, String.class),
            inline(null, String.class))
            .from(table("repository.site"), table("repository.buffer_type"))
            .where(field("s_name").eq(cast(null, String.class)))
            .and(field("bt_external_id").eq(cast(null, Integer.class))))
        .onConflict().doNothing()
    .getSQL();
```

Or even better, use the code generator, in case of which all of this will be done for you automatically, improving readability.

Comment: Actually I figured it out some time after posting question , appreciate your prompt answers